# Protocol Buffer for PHP

Tags: php, protocol-buffers

What are the avaliable libraries for using protobuf in PHP?

Comment: Full list of 3rd party and official implementations: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns

Comment: @marc , "Full" is not that full with regards to PHP pb4php looks abendoned

Comment: "full" in that implementors are free to ping the group to have things added/removed

Comment: Shame that this has been closed, as I'm now looking for a production PHP protobuf library, and can't find anything remotely decent. All of those projects are half baked

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Protocol_Buffer_for_PHP](http://code.google.com/p/pb4php/#Protocol_Buffer_for_PHP)

Last updated in May 2009

Implementing the Google "Protocol Buffer" for PHP, include parsing ...

Issue list: http://code.google.com/p/pb4php/issues/list

[Protobuf-PHP](https://github.com/drslump/Protobuf-PHP)

Last updated in April 2011

Protobuf for PHP is an implementation of Google's Protocol Buffers for the PHP language, supporting its binary data serialization and including a protoc plugin to generate PHP classes from .proto files.

Great effort has been put into generating PHP files that include all sort of type hints to aide IDE's with autocompletion. Therefore, it can not only be used to communicate with Protocol Buffers services but also as a generation tool for data objects no matter what the final serialization is.

Example:

```
$person = new Tutorial\Person();
$person->name = 'DrSlump';
$person->setId(12);

$book = new Tutorial\AddressBook();
$book->addPerson($person);

// Use default codec
$data = $book->serialize();

// Use custom codec
$codec = new \DrSlump\Protobuf\Codec\Binary();
$data = $codec->encode($book);
// ... or ...
$data = $book->serialize($codec);
```

[protoc-gen-php](https://github.com/bramp/protoc-gen-php)

Last updated December 05, 2010

This is a PHP Google Protocol Buffer Generator Plugin for protoc. It generates PHP code from a .proto file.

Comment: where can i find these? `$book = new Tutorial\AddressBook();`, `$person = new Tutorial\Person();`

Comment: you generate them from a protopuf spec

Comment: can you elaborate please? is this a class i should look for?

Comment: see the quick example here http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

Comment: i get an error `Fatal error: Class 'Tutorial\Person' not found in /var/www/myfolder/sample.php on line 5`

Comment: that example is not for `PHP`

Comment: did you generate the PHP classes from the protoc?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17338/discussion-between-t-q-and-oluies)

Comment: So is there a working example? I'm trying to get my head around this

Answer (score 8):

There is also https://github.com/drslump/Protobuf-PHP

Last updated December 2013.

Requirements (from the Github page):

- PHP 5.3
- Pear's Console_CommandLine (for the protoc wrapper tool)
- Google's protoc compiler version 2.3 or above
- GMP or BC Math extensions ¹

  ¹ Only needed for negative values in int32, int64 or fixed64 types.
  See the known issues section.

Answer (score 6):

If performance is your concern you might try [PHP Protobuf](https://github.com/allegro/php-protobuf).

It is PHP Protocol Buffers implementation written as an extension in C. Even though it is C code has no external dependencies including original Google's implementation.

PHP Protobuf comes with quite complete documentation.